# How do I group in power BI?

Tags: database-design, datatable, powerbi, data-visualization, dax

I am taking information from the project table as below:

| Project | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | 12531 |
| A13 | 123531 |
| A1 | 5631 |
| B123 | 181 |
| B13 | 1969 |
| B31 | 12865 |

I want to make it into two groups still under projects. So on powerBI I right click Project and create group and I name the group/create as followed. Where I create an A group and move all the a to member and group and the same for B.

| A | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | 12531 |
| A13 | 123531 |
| A1 | 5631 |

The B table

| B | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| B123 | 181 |
| B13 | 1969 |
| B31 | 12865 |

From there I created a new table with values as cost and row as A and B. I am getting all the line items. I want it to be one bucket that I can drill into, something like the table below:

| Project | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| A | Sum(A) |
| B | Sum(B) |

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I would go with having a new Column "Project Type". Fill this based on the first letter of the Project. Please do not go with new tables, you need to think as working wiht database, not excel sheets.

Comment: What would the code look like in powerBI?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a new calculated column to extract the leftmost character.

```
Project Type = LEFT ( Table1[Project )
```

[image: Calculated column screenshot]

Then you can easily create a table visual like you describe with a bit of drag and drop.

[image: Table visual screenshot]